# не хватает php intl & xsl расширений при установке Magento 2 на контрольной точке

Tags: php, windows, dll, magento, mamp

Я пробую запустить установщик Magento на Windows 7 с MAMP 3.3.0 . При запуске проверка готовности говорит: *xsl* и *intl* extension is missing. Оба *dll* находятся в `/ext` папке .

Есть 2 *php.ini* файла в папке `conf/php7.0.13/` : *php.ini-development* и *php.ini-production*. Строчки с xsl и intl в  обоих php.ini раскомментировал .

Скопировал icu***.dll файлы с папки `php` в `apache/bin`, но все-равно получаю туже ошибку.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это пофиксить. Если что-то непонятно обьяснил, какая инфа нужна, чтоб это исправить?

Comment: Вызовите phpinfo() и посмотрите какой php.ini файл используется и проверьте есть ли в нём эти расширения, если есть попробуйте указать полный путь

Comment: 1) phpinfo() сказал, что Loaded Configeration File это `conf/php7.0.13/php.ini`
2) также, что Configeration File (php.ini) Path это `c:\Windows` . этого файла там нет. решил попробовать добавить в Path путь в папку с php.ini . phpinfo() показал, что ничего не поменялось
3) пробую запустить php как модуль apache добавив в "httpd.conf" : строчки LoadModule php7_module "~/bin/php/php7apache2_2.dll" и PHPIniDir "~/php/php7.0.13" . ничего.
4) добавляю php.ini в c:\Windows, чтоб phpinfo() читал как он хочет. опять ничего. а когда удалил php.ini из корня, то инсталлер стал ругать все сразу

Comment: Возможно, это не совсем корректный ответ, но для меня решением стало: 1) установить Ubuntu 2) потом установить LAMP 3) потом установить Magento.